# less expensive alternative arduino board to CMUcam4

Tags: hardware

Is there any similar (less expensive alternative) arduino board to CMUcam4?

CMUcam4:The CMUcam4 is a fully programmable embedded computer vision sensor. The main processor is the Parallax P8X32A (Propeller Chip) connected to an OmniVision 9665 CMOS camera sensor module.

Comment: What's a CMUcam4?

Comment: @Majenko www.cmucam.org.

Comment: @IgorStoppa I can't click that, and copying and pasting is as onerous as using google to look it up for myself.  My dig was to try and get Rwy5 to provide a link (and even a little information) in the question...

Comment: I'm waiting for a bitbake build to complete, so trying to kill time :-)

Comment: OpenCV on Raspberry or Beaglebone.

Answer (score 1):

I have used OpenCV on Intel Galileo for doing recognition of sub images from a larger image (given the cover of a magazine, identify it in a pile of magazines partially covering it). The frame rate is far from stellar.
I haven't tried with Edison but it should be much faster, as it's an Atom core vs the pentium-like Quark. OpenCV is optimized for x86.

I used a normal webcam to capture the image, so this solution gives more flexibility in the choice of the sensor.

You could have a look at [ROS on Edison](http://wiki.ros.org/Edison).